# Wmic & GPRESULT output wrong

Tags: windows, batch-file, output, wmic, policies

i need assistance on a error showed to me when i try to did it on command line:

```
wmic /node:brspd030 computersystem get caption >>\\brspd010\c$\users\machael1\desktop\gpresult.txt & psexec \\brspd030 gpresult -r | findstr /i "WSUS" >>\\brspd010\c$\users\machael1\desktop\gpresult.txt
```

Output:

> Caption   
>   BRSPD010  
>   ††††浏慹圠啓⁓流畂楳敮獳䍐൳ †††传祭⁡南单䄠䉭獵湩獥偳獃਍††††䵅䅅圠啓⁓敒潰瑲牥൳

Ideal output:
caption and result from the Wsus research in the gpresult, i will use this command in the loop with some computers `"for %i in (.txt)`.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Your question states that an error was shown to you, but you appear not to have provided us with any error. _It looks to me like your commands have both worked_.

Answer (score 3):

The output of the `wmic` command is BOM prefixed two bytes per character utf-16le encoded, but the output of the `gpresult` is 1 byte per character ansi encoded. When read, each two bytes of the `gpresult` output are handled as one character and seen as indicated.

Maybe the easiest way to solve it is to filter the output of the `wmic` command

```
wmic computersystem get caption | more >> outputFile.txt
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
>>\\brspd010\c$\users\machael1\desktop\gpresult.txt ((wmic /node:brspd030 computersystem get caption | more) & (psexec \\brspd030 gpresult -r | findstr /i "WSUS"))
```

Comment: Nevermind, being also a non native English speaker I'm glad I can sometimes help, knowing of my own mistakes especially in comments which are only correctible for 5 minutes.

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply. could you give to me a way to solve my problem?

Comment: i need to sent a command line to receive in a txt file the name of the computer with the WSUS (gpresult) result as i showed in the command line.

Comment: @EliveltonAndrade, answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tested and it is working, but only a question, when i try to do with "for", doesn't paste in txt the "gpresult". below the code that i tried use.
for /f %1 in (user_plant.txt) do >>\\brspd010\c$\users\machael1\desktop\gpresult.txt ((wmic /node:%1 computersystem get caption | more) & (psexec \\%1 gpresult -r | findstr /i "WSUS"))
could you help again?

Comment: i found my error, sorry. Thanks for your reply, do you know any way to i learn windows command better ? i'd like to learn.